# Implement Adobe Photoshop's "Levels" feature using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, photoshop, gimp

In Adobe photoshop, I used the "Levels" feature to adjust Shadows, Midtones and Highlights of an image. I need an elegant solution using ffmpeg to implement the same effect. A ffmpeg implementation will help me perform the operation programmatically.

I've tried using the colorbalance filter available on ffmpeg.

`ffplay -i input -vf colorbalance=rs=-0.75:gs=-0.75:bs=-0.75:rm=-0.875:gm=-0.875:bm=-0.875:rh=-1:gh=-1:bh=-1`

In photoshop I'm able to achieve the expected results with the following settings,

```
Shadows - 199
Midtones - midpoint
Highlights - 255
```

Comment: No it doesn't. In photoshop, the levels settings I'm aiming for converts all three primary colors to black and only white portions of the image is retained.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the Levels window: https://ibb.co/FqtZ3ZV

Comment: Here's the alv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p25aelf7n3s0x5v/sample.alv?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## colorlevels

Use the [colorlevels](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorlevels) filter and interpolate the values to match Photoshop:

[image]
[image][image]
<sub>Original, Photoshop, ffmpeg</sub>

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "colorlevels=rimin=199/255:gimin=199/255:bimin=199/255" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Since you're only directly adjusting the input black points you only need to adjust `*min` options as shown in the example.

## curves

If you're familiar with Curves in Photoshop you can save the preset and load the ACV file with the [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "curves=psfile=file.acv" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using ffmpeg to only adjust min worked for me. When I try to load the preset acv file, I get a "Undefined constant or missing '(' in '.acv'" error. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: ffmpeg -i input -vf "curves=preset=file.acv" -frames:v 1 output

Comment: @user6434902 There was a typo in my example. Try `psfile=file.acv`.