# Multiply the video with a scalar with FFMPEG

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have to adjust a video which was too dark. In openCV, I simply used `Img.Mul()` to multiply each of the RGB band with a same scalar and got good result.

Could one do the equivalent operation with FFMPEG? I tried `eq` with contrast and brightness, but it was not quite the same thing.

**Edit** : thanks to a clue in @VC.One's answer below I was able to emulate `Img.Mul()` with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.file -vf colorlevels=rimax=0.5:gimax=0.5:bimax=0.5 -c:a copy output.file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to increase the **levels** of pixel brightness.

You can try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738185/2057709

If you've worked with image curves (in some photo editor) then also try: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/13110/17929

```
curves=r='X/Y':g='X/Y':b='X/Y'
```

The above curves method is nearest to increasing the input of each R-G-B channel.
 Where the `X` and `Y` are numbers ranging from `0.0` up to `1.0`. 
I recommend **X** of 0.5 and then you can test for the right **Y** value.

Comment: Thank you! Using colorlevels=rimax=0.5:gimax=0.5:bimax=0.5 has exactly the same effect as Img.Mul().